# Display Folder Property:"Contains"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using following code to count the number of files in a folder. However, if there are more than 500 files it would be hard to loop through each file. So my question is, is it possible to fetch the Folder property -"Contains" instead of looping through each file.

```
Sub pdfcount()
    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\FPY\"
    path = FolderPath &"\*.pdf"
    Filename = Dir(path)
    Do While Filename <>""
        count = count +1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Range("A1").Value = count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The below function will return the number of files in a folder.

```
Function CountFiles(folderPath As String) As Long

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim files As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set files = fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files

    CountFiles = files.Count

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Gareth,That was quick :)

Comment: Oops!!Checked it now  again.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, however it looks like OP wants to count how many PDF's appear in a folder; you can't pass wild cards through to an fso filepath?

Comment: @luke_t you are right.I want to count the pdf files and just realized if there are sub folders the answer provided by Gareth will not work.@Gareth so for being unclear here The folderpath contains sub folders too.

Comment: @Neelesh The way you're originally counting the files is the quickest, as far as I am aware. I do not believe there are any built-in methods to work with filtered files within a folder.